# Is it possible to read data on a private data collection on HLF when not on the policy, but the collection config "memberOnlyRead": false

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying and failing miserably to read data on a HLF collection as ORG1 on a collection 'owned' by ORG2.

I'm using the fabric-sample test network.

Flow

1. Org2 creates a document in it's collection called 'testCollection' using `putPrivateData,'`

```
await ctx.stub.putPrivateData(
      `testCollection`,
      '1',
      Buffer.from(stringify(sortKeysRecursive(DATA)))),
    );
```

2. Org1 wants to read a document in 'testCollection' with a valid key. `getPrivateData`

```
      const reportAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getPrivateData(
        `diagnosticReportCollection`,
        "1",
      );
```

My config looks like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "testCollection",
    "policy": "OR('Org2MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 1,
    "blockToLive":3,
    "memberOnlyRead": false,
    "memberOnlyWrite": true,
    "endorsementPolicy": {
      "signaturePolicy": "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
    }
  }
]
```

When I try to run this in a simple app, it creates the document, but when trying to read as ORG1 I get a error
`GET_STATE failed: transaction ID: 6e35148f51e33cb5c7dc5af5e591e2af81cd0e458ee5ece2191c9488549bed6c: private data matching public hash version is not available.`

Am I totally missing the mark here?

----Edit 9/12

Here is my app gateway code. From this article
https://kctheservant.medium.com/private-data-collection-policy-demonstrating-members-only-read-and-write-features-b2e03ff02332

I think I'm dealing with scenario two, I guess I don't know how to (as Org2) Specify I want org1 to specify that org2 needs to process the query?

```html
async function main(): Promise<void> {
  const clientOrg1 = await newGrpcConnection(
    tlsCertPathOrg1,
    peerEndpointOrg1,
    peerNameOrg1,
  );

  const gatewayOrg1 = connect({
    client: clientOrg1,
    identity: await newIdentity(certPathOrg1, mspIdOrg1),
    signer: await newSigner(keyDirectoryPathOrg1),
  });

  const clientOrg2 = await newGrpcConnection(
    tlsCertPathOrg2,
    peerEndpointOrg2,
    peerNameOrg2,
  );

  const gatewayOrg2 = connect({
    client: clientOrg2,
    identity: await newIdentity(certPathOrg2, mspIdOrg2),
    signer: await newSigner(keyDirectoryPathOrg2),
  });

  const contractOrg1 = gatewayOrg1
    .getNetwork(channelName)
    .getContract(chaincodeName);

  // Get the smart contract as an Org2 client.
  const contractOrg2 = gatewayOrg2
    .getNetwork(channelName)
    .getContract(chaincodeName);

  try {

    console.log("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ As Org1  Client ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    console.log("\n Org one creates a report");
    // Create Report as Org1
    // await createReport(contractOrg1);
    try {
      console.log("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ As Org2 Client ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
      console.log("\n Org Two reads report and copies it to Org1");
      // Read report as Org1

      const report = await readReport(contractOrg2);
      console.log(report);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error:  " + e);
    }
  } finally {
    gatewayOrg1.close();
    clientOrg1.close();

    gatewayOrg2.close();
    clientOrg2.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you send the request to an Org1 peer ? If so then it's not going to work and that's totally expected otherwise it wouldn't be private to Org2 and defeats the concept of private data. An Org1 identity could send the request to an Org2 peer and then the private data information can be read, but then it's upto the chaincode to enforce access rules

Comment: I'm sending a request as an Org1.Peer to an Org2.Peer. Is there anyway to read a Orgs2 Collection as Org1?

Comment: And maybe I'm saying this incorrectly, I'm using a Org1 gateway in the  app. I'm pretty new at HLF so I could just be royally fubarring explaining this.

Comment: What identity are you using to sign the endorsement and how are you then sending it to Org2 ? If you send it to an Org1 Peer Gateway service then I don't think that will work either because it's likely (depending on block heights) that that Org1 Peer will do a simulation of that endorsement first and so won't work

Comment: I'm sending it via an Org2 gateway.

Comment: All I can suggest is check the peer logs with debug on to make sure that the org2 gateway is trying to invoke on an org2 peer that has the private data. Alternatively try using org targeting in your client application to force the gateway to send the request only to org2. Also requiredPeerCount of 0 is not recommended so maybe try increasing that. The other thing is block to live is low try increasing that as the data may have been deleted. Other than that, sorry out of ideas and really need to delve into peer debug logs to determine what is going on

Comment: I appreciate all your help, I think I may have found a medium article that talks about almost exactly what I'm trying to do 

https://kctheservant.medium.com/private-data-collection-policy-demonstrating-members-only-read-and-write-features-b2e03ff02332 
<--- Scenario 2. 

They do something while getting a peer of Org1 to process this query, Is that something that can be done via  fabric gateway?